# Send PSCustomObject as body parameter in Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I have a JSON containing an array of URL + body objects.

```
> $categories[0]

url       body
---       ----
https:XXX @{custom_field_value_id=12345}
```

When I call

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method POST -Uri url  -Body ($categories[0].body|ConvertTo-Json)
```

I get HTTP 500 from the server.

When I call

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method POST -Uri "https://XXX"  -Body @{custom_field_value_id=12345}
```

it works.

Any hints? I guess it's a typo / type matching type of error. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the `body` property contains a string `@{custom_field_value_id=12345}`. In your second command, you are sending a hash table to the `-Body` parameter. You will need to convert I think --> `-Body ($categories[0].body -replace '^@{|}$' | ConvertFrom-Stringdata)`. The better way is to just fix `Body` property to contain a hash table from the beginning.

Comment: The definitive way to see what the problem is and how to fix it is run your browser debugger and look at the data that's POST'd in both scenarios.  That way, you can see what the data structure looks like on success and compare it to the one that's failing to identify what needs to change.  Chrome -> F12 -> Network Tab -> Params/Response tabs (to the right)

Comment: @AdminOfThings, it works. Thanks mate!
Just to let me clearly understand the magic. 
The "-replace '^@{|}$'" embraces the body with curly brackets?
thepip3r, those commands are called from Powershell. Any hints how to call them from Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$categories[0]` object contains a `body` property with a string value `@{custom_field_value_id=12345}`. When you pass `@{custom_field_value_id=12345}` directly into the `-Body` parameter of [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7), it is treated as a `[HashTable]`. For your first example code to treat the `-Body` value the same as the second, you will need to convert your string into a hash table.

```
$body = $categories[0].body -replace '^@{|}$' | ConvertFrom-Stringdata
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method POST -Uri $categories[0].url  -Body $body
```

`-replace` uses regex matching and then replaces the matched characters with the replacement string. Since we leaving off the replacement string, the replacement is essentially a removal of the match characters.

`^@{` matches the beginning of the string (`^`) and literal characters `@{`. `|` is an alternation (an `OR`). `}` is the literal `}` character. `$` matches the end of the string.

The goal is to remove all extra characters leaving behind a `key=value` syntax. That syntax can be piped to [ConvertFrom-Stringdata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7), which will convert the data into a hash table.

I believe the best solution is to fix the data at the source before it is queried so that `body` already contains the appropriate data type.

Comment: Thank you! Not only you helped to solve the initial problem, but thanks to your explanation, I was able to understand and provide by myself a solution to a similar problem.